# обновления android 9 не применились в bootloader

Tags: android

всем привет у меня на телефоне стоял **android one**
и как то раз прилетели обновления на **android 9**
я их установил и система загружается как  **android 9**,
но если перезагрузить телефон то при загрузке пишет **android one** хотя загружается **android 9**,
с чем это может быть связанно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android One и Android 9 - это разные вещи.

Первая - это вариант сборки ОС подразумевающий различные оптимизации, с целью возможности запуска на слабых девайсах.

Вторая - это собственно версия ОС, а не вариант сборки этой версии.

Т.е. у вас, вроде, нет никакой проблемы с телефоном и софтом под него. Версию ОС вы можете проверить в настройках девайса - там должно будет отображаться `9` в качестве номера версии.